# Using super keyword

Tags: ruby, super

Can someone please explain to me why this code gives me an ArgumentError yet when using super without arguments ruby automatically passes the arguments that were inherited from the superclass or am I wrong

This is the code:

```
class Point 
  def initialize (x, y)
    @x = x
    @y = y
  end
end

class Point3D < Point 
  def initialize (x, y, z)
    super
    @z = z
  end
end
```

Comment: Sorry about the code I didn't know how to write a code in this site

Comment: You can use ``` to start a code block :)

Comment: I edited your question to format the code and change `Class` to `class`, `Def` to `def` and `Super` to `super`. `Class`, `Def` and `Super` are incorrect and would have generated exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try the following code snippet for your problem:

```
class Point
  def initialize(x, y)
    @x = x
    @y = y
  end
end

class Point3D < Point
  def initialize(x, y, z)
    super(x, y) # Pass the arguments here
    @z = z
  end
end
```

As a quick summary, if you call super with no arguments, the arguments are automatically passed to the superclass's constructor then.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the error and use your assumption that when `super` is called without arguments it passes all arguments to its parent you can see why it does not work.

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2))
```

The error says you passed 3 instead of 2 arguments at some point (the `super` call). It actually passes ALL arguments, not just first few arguments if the ancestor method accepts less arguments. It is like calling `Point.new(1,2,3)` which would return the same error.

In a case where ancestor method accepts different number of arguments you have to specify these arguments manually and therefore define your class initializer this way:

```rb
class Point3D < Point
  def initialize(x, y, z)
    super(x,y)
    @z = z
  end
end
```

Comment: How does your answer differ from @41726c's earlier answer?

Comment: @CarySwoveland My understanding is that OP already knew that "arguments are automatically passed" (it is written in the question) and I suppose they also knew that it would work with `super(x,y)`. The question was why it does not work without arguments, which @41726c does not explain.

Comment: Is that not explained in his last sentence (though the wording could be improved)?

Comment: @CarySwoveland  41726c wrote "the arguments are automatically passed to the superclass's constructor", OP wrote "ruby automatically passes the arguments that were inherited from the superclass". OP's wording is not good (it implies the data flow in the wrong direction) however I think they understood the concept and only did not realize that if the argument count does not match it wouldn't guess you want the first N arguments but it would raise an exception instead.

Comment: I think it would have been better to have left a comment on 41 72 6c's answer suggesting a clarification than posting an answer that was only slightly different than that one. Others may disagree, of course.